# Optimizing formula parameters using information calulated from data frame

Tags: r

I am trying to calculate parameters to a formula using information calculated from a fairly complicated data frame. The format of the data frame (simplified)

```
Id  t_past  ref  Y
1   1       2.0  0.3
1   6       1.3  0.3
1   11      0.9  0.3
2   1       3.1  0.9
2   12      15.0 0.9
```

I have been trying to use dplyr to solve the formula that estimates Y for each Id and then feed the result into optim() without any success. I gather optim() wants a numeric matrix that it can examine for data? Here is what I have tried so far:

```
    library(dplyr)
    optFn <- function(dat, par) {

      sumFn <- function(r, p) {
        sum <- 0
        for(i in 1:length(r)) {
          if(!is.na(r[i]))  {
            yf <- p[1] * exp(-p[2] * r[i])
            sum <- sum + yf * 0.1
          }
        }
        return(sum)
      }

      dat %>%  group_by(Id) %>%
     summarise(pred = sumFn(Ref, par), y = max(y)) %>%
     select(pred,y) %>%
  transmute(se = (pred - y)^2) -> SE

  return(sum(SE$se))
}
# Create some test data
actualFn <- function(x) {
  0.2 * exp( -0.3 * x) + 0.01 * rnorm(1)
}

hr <- seq(1, 60, by=6)
mp <- rep(hr, 100)
refVals <- seq(-17.5, 65.0, length.out=100)
ref <- as.vector(sapply(refVals, function (x) rep(x, 10)))
y <- actualFn(refVals)
y <- as.vector(sapply(y, function (x) rep(x, 10)))
IdVals <- seq(1, 100, by=1)
Id <- as.vector(sapply(IdVals, function (x) rep(x, 10)))
testDat <- data.frame(Id=Id, minutes_past=mp, Ref=ref, y=y)

# This doesn't work
#result <- optim(par = c(runif(1), runif(1)), fn=optFn, gr=NULL, data = testDat)
```

Maybe there's some better approach for tuning the parameters of a formula to given data. There are many fields, some of which I would like to try adding to the formula, and uneven time steps for each Id, so I don't want to unpack everything into a numeric matrix if I can help it.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the documentation for `optim`, it tells you exactly what to do to make it work.

> fn
>
> A function to be minimized (or maximized), with **first argument the
>   vector of parameters over which minimization is to take place**. It
>   should return a scalar result.

Anything extra that you need to provide to `fn` after the first argument, you can pass as one of the `...` arguments.

In your code you're providing `optFn` for `fn`. `optFn`'s first argument is `dat`, which is not a "vector of parameters". After that you're passing an argument called "data". But your function `optFn` doesn't have any argument called "data". All it has is "dat".

So just fix those two lines:

```
optFn <- function(par, dat) {
```

and

```
result <- optim(par = c(runif(1), runif(1)), fn=optFn, gr=NULL, dat = testDat)
```

Now it works great.

https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/optim.html

Comment: I was just following code I'd found online which seemed to be set up this way. Good to know that optim isn't trying to some sort of operation on the data to figure out what sort of surface it is exploring. This helps figuring out errors.